# Improving this AJAX function to update a "like this" link

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I asked a question about this but the post degenerated into confusion which lost the gist of the problem.  Basically I'm trying to set up ajax so that a "like" or "unlike" link updates a database and shows the new status without having to refresh the page.

So I have a "view.php" page with links which are produced by a PHP loop.  They look like this:

```
<div class="tools">
<a href="processor.php?c=cars&p=2&s=d&u=i&pid=999999990" title="Click to LIKE this photo" class="like do_like">like</a>
</div>

<div class="tools">
<a href="processor.php?c=cars&p=2&s=d&u=d&pid=999999991" title="Click to UNLIKE this photo" class="like do_unlike">unlike</a>
</div>
```

Note that each link has two classes: firstly a "like" class, and then either a "do_like" class or a "do_unlike" class, according to whether it's a link to "like" or a link to "unlike" respectively. (Originally I only had the "do_like" and "do_unlike" classes, which I was using to transform the link via css into a rollover-type image/icon, but I added the "like" class as well, for the ajax - see below.)

When a user clicks one of these links, the receiving processor.php script takes the variable-value pairs from the query string, and uses them to update a database, and then build a new form of the link, which it echoes out. The new form of the link is such that a "like this" link turns into an "unlike this" link, and vice-versa.  So for the first "like" link above, the database returns:

```
processor.php?c=cars&p=2&s=d&u=d&pid=999999990
```

It's the "u" variable in the query string which determines whether or not the processor.php page will either insert the data into the database in the case of a "like" (u=i), or delete the data from the database in the case of an "unlike" (u=d).  (I'm using prepared PDO statements for the database inserts/deletions.)

I'm using jquery/ajax to insert this newly built link in place of the one that was clicked, without having to refresh the page.

To do this, in the "view.php" page I included jquery.js and used the following javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("a.like").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this);
    $.get(
        $(this).attr('href'),
        function(data){
            link.attr('href',data);
    });
});
});
</script>
```

The problem is, although this function sends the data to the processing script OK, and changes the link's href attribute in the page without a page refresh (I can see it's doing this OK by copying the link in the browser after a click), it doesn't change the link's text, class or title.  So I as it is, I have to refresh the page to see any visual cues that the link has in fact changed (I might as well just use a header redirection in the processor.php page).

How can I modify the function (or change it) so that it **also** replaces the link's text, class and title?  So that (for example, transforming a "like" link):

```
<a href="processor.php?c=cars&p=2&s=d&u=i&pid=999999990" title="Click to LIKE this photo" class="like do_like">like</a>
```

becomes:

```
<a href="processor.php?c=cars&p=2&s=d&u=d&pid=999999990" title="Click to UNLIKE this photo" class="like do_unlike">unlike</a>
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Use an if condition to check the current state and update the attributes.

```
$(function () {

    $("a.like").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this);           
        var alreadyLiked = (link.text() == "UnLike") ? true : false;            
        $.get(link.attr('href'), function (data) {
        link.attr('href', data);
        if (alreadyLiked) {
            link.removeClass("do_unlike").addClass("do_like").text("Like").attr("title", "Click to LIKE this photo");

        }
        else {
            link.removeClass("do_like").addClass("do_unlike").text("UnLike").attr("title", "Click to UN LIKE this photo");
        }
        alreadyLiked = !alreadyLiked;           
    });

    });
});
```

This code will work. Tested. Assuming every time the get request gives you the url (for deleting/inserting ) correctly.

Comment: I tried this - I had to add `});` to close the initial `$(function() {` but even then the result is the same as before - the link's text, class and title weren't updated.

Comment: @JohnDoe : I updated my answer with one working( tested) version.

Comment: That works for two clicks, then sticks on the last state.  However I solved the problem myself - see my answer.  It's an amalgam of your answer and Pitchinnate's solution, so thanks to both of you for the inspiration!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the class and the title then also:

```
[...]
$.get(
    $(this).attr('href'),
    function(data){
        link.attr('href',data);
        link.toggleClass('do_like do_unlike');
        link..attr('title', 'change title here');
});
```

Comment: This is the closest to my solution so far, as the changing of the class now works, and so allows me to use the changing classes to indicate the current like status by css sprite-type rollover images (which does away with my need to change the link text - or even have a link text).  That's brilliant, but, after deleting the extra period in `link..attr('title', 'change title here');` the changing of the title doesn't really work, as it just sticks forever at the "_change title here_" text.  Shame there isn't a `toggleTitle`, or something to replicate that..

Comment: Yeah you would have to pass the title or check to see the current value like Shyju suggested. I was just showing you how to change it.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on both Shyju's and Pitchinnate's responses (so thanks to both!), and it works a treat using the css rollover link-transformation method (I also included a fade effect):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("a.like").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this);
    $.get(
        $(this).attr('href'),
        function(data){
            link.attr('href',data);
            link.toggleClass('do_like do_unlike');

var titleState=(link.attr("title") == "Click to LIKE this photo") ? "no" : "yes";
if(titleState=="yes")
    {
    link.attr('title', 'Click to LIKE this photo');
    }
    else
    {
    link.attr('title', 'Click to UNLIKE this photo');
    }

    });

$(this).parents('div.tools').fadeOut(1000);
$(this).parents('div.tools').fadeIn('slow');

});
});
</script>
```